# Is there a way to read ApplicationManifest.xml from C# code and retrieve values?

Tags: c#, azure-service-fabric

I'm curious is there a way to place some values exactly (**and only**) into ApplicationManifest.xml file and then read them inside a C# code?

I know that it is possible to define some variables inside ServiceManifest.xml, then add a special override section in the ApplicationManifest.xml and retrieve these values with `GetConfigurationPackageObject` method. This is not what I want.

Comment: What are you trying to store?

Comment: @MatthewWhited: string values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Application parameters are the closest thing but, as you already know, those get plumbed through the ConfigOverrides section and into the Settings.xml file in individual services' config packages.